# javafx screen flickers then goes black

Tags: java, screen, javafx, javafx-8

I just started to program in javafx, I installed the java 1.8 beta jdk and a beta build of eclipse. I followed the [circle example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/animation.htm#BABCJFJC). All goes well except when i resize the window that comes up the screen flickers for a bit, and then goes completely black. I then added a label to the scene, and weirdly enough the label still shoes when the screen goes black. I checked to make sure i have the latets video card drivers installed, so that does not seem te be the issue. I tried to search online, but no one seems to have this issue (only issues that their screen is black to begin with)

What could possibly be the issue that causes my window to go black once i resize it.

EDIT:
It seems that when i start to move the window around the circles appear for a split second and then disappear again

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the beta Java 8. You can file an issue with a description of your environment (OS/Java 8 build number/Graphics Card, etc) against the runtime project in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com)

Comment: thank you for the tip, i just filled out the details on their form :)

Comment: I've seen this issue several times, on several different Windows machines.  I think there may be a bug where the window isn't repainting enough.